# Is it possible in sql to group by fields matching some pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-like

Is it possible in SQL to do grouping by `LIKE` patterns? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
id|name  
1 | Mike  
2 | Bob  
3 | Bill  
4 | Alice
```

and then doing query like: `SELECT name from users group by _pattern_`
For example I would like to get groups by matching patterns 'B*', '*l*' and 'Mike'
would give the output:

```
B*  | Bob
    | Bill
*l* | Bill
    | Alice
Mike| Mike
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 'B*' as Mask, Name
from Table
WHERE Name like 'B%'
UNION ALL
Select '*l*' as Mask, Name
from Table
WHERE Name like '%l%'
UNION ALL
Select 'Mike' as Mask, Name
from Table
WHERE Name like 'Mike'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same record to appear multiple times according to the pattern it matches, you should use multiple `SELECT` statements with the relevant filters and `UNION` them together..

Answer (score 0):

You can query against the patterns in a set structure then GROUP BY or DISTINCT to remove dups, below is a way with an MSSQL CTE (temp table/table var would work also);

```
with match (pattern) as (
          select 'B%'
    union select '%l%' 
    union select 'Mike' 
)
select
    pattern,
    name
from TABLE, match where TABLE.name like match.pattern
group by pattern, name

==
%l%     Alice
%l%     Bill
B%      Bill
B%      Bob
Mike    Mike
```