# How to return similar values obtained through LIKE operator as one value?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

This is a test mysql query that I'm using within a much larger query to filter out the operating systems from my table.

```
select distinct ostype from prus where ostype LIKE '%%android%%' OR ostype LIKE '%%ios%%' OR ostype LIKE '%%iOS%%';

  ostype
-----------------
 iOS
 generic_ios
 generic_android
 9_android
 M_android
 android
```

This query returns all kinds android and iOS versions stored.

Now I want to group together and have all android versions (generic_android,9_android,M_android, android) returned/displayed as one single name - Android and same for iOS (iOS, generic_ios) as iOS.

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible in sql to group by fields matching some pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352086/is-it-possible-in-sql-to-group-by-fields-matching-some-pattern)

Comment: Not really :) juergen d actually nailed it, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct case when ostype LIKE '%%android%%' then 'Android'
                     when ostype LIKE '%%ios%%' then 'IOS'
                     else ostype 
                end as filtered_ostype
from prus
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using group_concat

```
select group_concat( ostype ) 
from prus 
where ostype LIKE '%%android%%' 
  OR ostype LIKE '%%ios%%' 
  OR ostype LIKE '%%iOS%%';
```